# How can I add an IP address to iptable or firewall using JAVA?

Tags: networking, java, iptables, firewall

I have built a Monitoring System : [Shadow-NET](https://github.com/Sagher/Shadow-NET) in java. I have a web interface which shows black listed IPs.

Now I am required to provide an option on web ui which will allow the user to block any of the IP listed. Is there any way to block any specified IP address i.e. by adding it to the iptable or configuring the firewall, in java?

Comment: You most likely will need to `exec' iptables from your JAVA, but that would require you to run JAVA as a root, which seems less than ideal.

Comment: I already run JAVA as a root, due to the fact that I am capturing the traffic using jnetpcap and without the root I cannot seem to access the NICs.

Comment: Right on, there are always exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocking an ip with `iptables` is simply enough.  Getting it from your app to the system might have security implications.  If you use System.exec() the command would have to be ran as root.

Here is an example for blocking the ip 1.2.3.4 in iptables.

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
```